# MediaFileUpload of HTML in UTF-8 encoding using Python and Google-Drive-SDK

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, google-drive-api

[Looking for example using MediaFileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472401/looking-for-example-using-mediafileupload) has a reference to the basic documentation for creating/uploading a file to Google Drive.

However, while I have code that creates files, converting from HTML to Google Doc format.  It works perfectly when they contain only ASCII characters, but when I add a non-ASCII character, it fails, with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\my\py\ckwort.py", line 949, in <module>
    rids, worker_documents = analyze( meta, gd )
  File "d:\my\py\ckwort.py", line 812, in analyze
    gd.mkdir( **iy )
  File "d:\my\py\ckwort.py", line 205, in mkdir
    self.create( **( kw['subop']))
  File "d:\my\py\ckwort.py", line 282, in create
    media_body=kw['media_body'],
  File "D:\my\py\gdrive2\oauth2client\util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\my\py\gdrive2\apiclient\http.py", line 676, in execute
    headers=self.headers)
  File "D:\my\py\gdrive2\oauth2client\util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\my\py\gdrive2\oauth2client\client.py", line 420, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "D:\my\py\gdrive2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1597, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "D:\my\py\gdrive2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1345, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "D:\my\py\gdrive2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1282, in _conn_request
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 812, in _send_output
    msg += message_body
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 370: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't find any parameter to use to specify what file encoding should be used by MediaFileUpload (My files are using UTF-8). Am I missing something?

Later: It occurred to me to try adding

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

to each source file. Didn't hurt the ASCII ones, but didn't help those containing non-ASCII UTF-8 characters.

Later still: I've worked around the problem for now by using HTML entities (ASCII character sequences that represent Unicode characters) for all characters whose ordinal is greater than 127. But this shouldn't need to be.

Comment: It looks like a client lib bug, could you file it under https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/issues/list?

Comment: OK, reported as Issue 49 [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/issues/detail?id=49&thanks=49&ts=1382382938)

Comment: Is there a Python3 version of this library available?